# Changing colours of links in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitextview

Is it possible to change the font color of links in an UITextView? Because by default it is blue...

Answer (score 1):

By default no, If you want to do this you need to subclass the UITextView and overwrite the drawRect method.

Comment: Any tutorial on how to subclass the UITextView please?

Comment: Just create an new class and inherit it from UIView. After that in your .h file change in @interface line from : UIView to UITextView, and then do your custom drawing in drawRect method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and use HTML string and load that in a UIWebView insteaad of using a UITextView in such a way:

```
NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><script> document.ontouchmove = function(event) { if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) event.preventDefault(); } </script><style type='text/css'>* { margin:0; padding:0; } p { color:black; font-family:Helvetica; font-size:14px; } a { color:#63B604; text-decoration:none; }</style></head><body><p>%@</p></body></html>", yourText];
webText.delegate = self;
[webText loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```